# Can CGI elements emit light when in real video?

Tags: light

Blender super noob here.

Is it feasible to have, lets say, a neon sign made in Blender, emit light onto its surroundings when placed in a real life video?

Comment: this is feasible, but it requires manual laber. (I'm not very good at vfx, I'm just saying that it can be done.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would camera project parts of your video to objects within the Blender scene and those objects catch the surrounding light. Than you would comp it over your footage.

here is a small YT Video that shows the process with an Image but you can also use Video or Image Frames - but be aware that you have a good tracking or you will get sliding effects

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p9IfDeNU8K0

ohhh and for sure
BlenderGuru's Camera Mapping tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B9r9tKX5olY

if you set up your scene like this, you can have your NeonSign lighten Up the surrounding Areas.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will check out your recommendations!

Comment: @TylerKeene if you you find that answer helpful, please vote it p and tagg it as helpful so that other user with the same problem can find it easier and know that it can be a help.

Comment: @TylerKeene does it help you ?